# Make a custom file extension in C# (Windows 7)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-7, registry

I am trying to make a file extension associated to my application like make any file with .ztr work directly with my app when user double clicks that file.
I am using VS2012 , C# , Windows 7
I did simulate this example [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtYobuVvcFE).

Sure with some modification like fix Import Dll put also failed.

```
    public static void Register   (string Ext,string Program,string Ico)
    {
        string prog = Path.GetFileName(Program);
        RegistryKey file = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Classes\\"+Ext);//.osa
        RegistryKey App = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Classes\\Applications\\" + prog);//osama.exe
        RegistryKey Link = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\" + Ext);//.osa

        file.CreateSubKey("DefultIcon").SetValue("", Ico);
        file.CreateSubKey("PerceivedType").SetValue("","Text");

        App.CreateSubKey("shell\\open\\command").SetValue("", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"%1");
        App.CreateSubKey("shell\\edit\\command").SetValue("", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"%1");
        App.CreateSubKey("DefultIcon").SetValue("", Ico);

        //There is Change here you 
        Link.CreateSubKey("UserChoice").SetValue("Progid", Program);
        Invoke.SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x0000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Comment: this code doesnt work with : file not appear with My custome Icon and when I click file Windows give me options like Open With but not open My Application Directly , Can you help please

Comment: You've got `DefultIcon` spelled incorrectly.